# Problem with ï (LaTeX)

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, errors, packages

I want to write an "ï" in my document (French is a hard language).

I've tried `\''{\i}` and I've placed the brackets in many other ways but it still doesn't work... Please help me!

My 'configuration':

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,titlepage]{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage[frenchb,german]{babel}  
\usepackage{chemmacros}  
\usepackage{color}  
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{siunitx}  
\usepackage[backend=bibtex8,style=authortitle-ticomp,doi=false]{biblatex}
```

(I want to write the word "éthanoïque")

Thank you in advance if you have any answer (and please forgive my bad English)

Comment: `\"i` should work; note the double quote, not two single quotes.

Comment: Can you provide a full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864)? Did you really type `\''{\i}`, i.e. two single quotes? Correct would be `\"{\i}` with one double quote.

Comment: Note that some editors might convert `"` (double quotes) into different quotes automatically (TeXworks can do that, for example: Edit > Preferences > Editor > Smart Quotes mode > none). You'd have to disable this feature to get `"`, or copy it to the document.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Why don't you simply type `ï`?

Comment: you could use `\"i` or save your document in UTF-8 encoding and then change `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` to `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` then you can  use ï in the document

Comment: You are using latin1 encoding, so simply type the word "éthanoïque" in this encoding. All characters are included in this encoding. Where is problem?

Comment: as wipet and Bernard said ï is in latin1 (I was thinking you needed utf-8) using utf-8 is a good idea for other reasons but not needed here. You can just type ï directly.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Are you sure its OK to just type `ï` directly if the input encoding is `latin1`? The answer I posted would seem to suggest otherwise. Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: @Mico yes it works

Comment: Thank you for your answers! egreg's solution worked well, and thank you moewe for the advice, I've just modified my settings. I can't write ï, even with latin1, it might be a problem with TeXworks. Thanks once again, you're an awesome community!

Comment: I still can't write the double quote, I think this is due to my keyboard...

Comment: Have tried using `% !TEX encoding = ISO-8859-1` at the very begining of the document? You can set TexWorks for ISO-8859-1 in preferences/editor too. (Mais j'utiliserais utf8.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a simple typo `''` (two single quotes) vs `"` (one double quote).